# Ant + M2Eclipse Tutorial

Tags: eclipse, ant, m2eclipse

Does anyone know of an Ant + M2Eclipse tutorial? I have a Java project utilizing Maven for it's dependencies. The problem is when I use an Ant task for compiling the project, errors pop up because of the dependencies. Can anybody give me tips on how to define Maven dependencies in an Ant task (compile task to be more specific)?

Comment: Why would you like to use Ant for a Maven based project? Why not using Maven instead so you don't think about the dependencies etc. Furthermore this does not make sense (in my opinion; may be you have reasons?).

Comment: Well the Ant is used for building the large project. I mean Maven is good for dependency management but when it comes to building, Ant is still better for me.

Comment: Hm..I'm using Maven for about 5 years (I've worked a lot with Ant before). But Maven brings so much support out of the box which must be implemented in Ant before you can use it...I've build large projects with about 150 modules with maven so no problem we had so crude requirements for packaging (rpm, repackging for production configuration, integration tests etc.) which i solved via Maven...

Comment: The solution below is useful for teams that are on Ant projects but want to access Maven's repos to look at 3rd party source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did. It now works.

```
<artifact:dependencies
    pathId="dependency.classpath"
    filesetId="dependency.fileset">
    <remoteRepository refid="repository.url" />
    <pom refid="maven.project"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about calling Maven via Ant ?